# Showing only the first level of sub categories for the current category

Tags: php, magento

I am using the following code to display the sub categories of the current category you are own.

However I have 2 levels of sub cats so I need to be able to modify the code somehow to only show the 1st level of sub categories for the current category you are own instead of both levels?

```
<?php 
/* Load category by id */
$cat = Mage::registry('current_category');

 /*Returns comma separated ids*/
$subcats = $cat->getChildren();

foreach(explode(',',$subcats) as $subCatid)
{
    $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($subCatid);
    if($_category->getIsActive()) {
        echo '<li><a href="'.$_category->getURL().'" title="View the products for the  "'.$_category->getName().'" category">'.$_category->getName().'</a></li>';

        /* Load category by id */
        $sub_cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category->getId());

        /*Returns comma separated ids*/
        $sub_subcats = $sub_cat->getChildren();
        foreach(explode(',',$sub_subcats) as $sub_subCatid)
        {
            $_sub_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($sub_subCatid);
            if($_sub_category->getIsActive()) {
                echo '<li class="sub_cat"><a href="'.$_sub_category->getURL().'" title="View the products for the "'.$_sub_category->getName().'" category">'.$_sub_category->getName().'</a></li>';
            }
        }      
    }
}
?> `
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to show the first level subcategories, then just get rid of

```
/*Returns comma separated ids*/
$sub_subcats = $sub_cat->getChildren();
foreach(explode(',',$sub_subcats) as $sub_subCatid)
{
    $_sub_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($sub_subCatid);
    if($_sub_category->getIsActive()) {
        echo '<li class="sub_cat"><a href="'.$_sub_category->getURL().'" title="View the products for the "'.$_sub_category->getName().'" category">'.$_sub_category->getName().'</a></li>';
    }
}
```

Since you're now loading the current category through `$cat = Mage::registry('current_category');` and fetches is subcategories that you loop through (first level).

Answer (score 0):

You may use the `$_sub_category->getLevel()` to check the current level.

Try re-writing the below code

```
if($_sub_category->getIsActive()) {
```

to

```
if($_sub_category->getIsActive() && $_sub_category->getLevel() == 2) {
```

Please make sure `getLevel()` returns the appropriate level (can't remember it is 1,2 or 3).